# ASP Nested Loop returns error

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

im trying to create a nested loop for a menu but it returns error. please can someone help me fix this problem. or even identify where the loop went wrong.

```
Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A040E)
'loop' without 'do'
/asp/default.asp, line 64
loop until RS.EOF
```

**The Code**

```
msql = "SELECT * FROM tblMenu ORDER BY [link_position] ASC"
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set RSsub = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open msql, Conn, 1,3
RSsub.Open msql

If Not RS.EOF Then
    Do
        Response.Write "<li><a href="""& RS("link")&""" title ="""& RS("link_title")&""">"& RS("link_name") &"</a>"

        If NOT RSsub.EOF Then
            Response.Write("<ul>" & vbcrlf)
            Do While NOT RSsub.EOF
                Response.Write(RSsub("sub_menu") & vbcrlf)
                RSsub.MoveNext
            Loop
            Response.Write("</ul>" & vbcrlf)
            RSsub.Close

            Response.Write("</li>" & vbcrlf)        
            RS.MoveNext
    loop until RS.EOF
End if
```

**Expected Output**

```
<li><a href="some-link" title="">Record from DB</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="some-link">Records from DB</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `End If` for `If NOT RSsub.EOF Then`.

Comment: Thanks the loop is now fixed, but the output breaks the whole menu :(

Answer (score 2):

Several syntax errors. Here is the cleaned up code.

```
    msql = "SELECT * FROM tblMenu ORDER BY [link_position] ASC"
    RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    RSsub = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    RS.Open(msql, Conn, 1, 3)
    RSsub.Open(msql)

    If Not RS.EOF Then
        Do
            Response.Write("<li><a href=""" & RS("link") & """ title =""" & RS("link_title") & """>" & RS("link_name") & "</a>")

            If Not RSsub.EOF Then
                Response.Write("<ul>" & vbcrlf)
                Do While Not RSsub.EOF
                    Response.Write(RSsub("sub_menu") & vbcrlf)
                    RSsub.MoveNext()
                Loop
                Response.Write("</ul>" & vbcrlf)
                RSsub.Close()
            End If

            Response.Write("</li>" & vbcrlf)
            RS.MoveNext()
        Loop Until RS.EOF
    End If
```

UPDATES :

As per the image you posted, the sub_menu in your table is just a bunch of html li elements that you can directly append to response. You do not need a separate recordset to read the submenu. Try this code :

```
msql = "SELECT * FROM tblMenu ORDER BY [link_position] ASC"
RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
RS.Open(msql, Conn, 1, 3)

Do
    Response.Write("<li><a href=""" & RS("link") & """ title =""" & RS("link_title") & """>" & RS("link_name") & "</a>" & vbcrlf)

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpy(RS("sub_menu")) Then
        Response.Write("<ul class=""sub-menu"">" & vbcrlf)
        Response.Write(RS("sub_menu") & vbcrlf)
        Response.Write("</ul>" & vbcrlf)
    End If
    Response.Write("</li>" & vbcrlf)
    RS.MoveNext()
Loop Until RS.EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the cleaned up code but it returns an error `Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A0414)
Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub
/asp/default.asp, line 46, column 25
RS.Open(msql, Conn, 1, 3)`

Comment: @YAQOOB Replace `Response.Write("</ul>" & vbcrlf)` with `Response.Write "</ul>" & vbcrlf`.

Comment: @Dai i've made the changes as you asked, but now this error came up `ADODB.Recordset (0x800A0E78)
Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.`

Comment: @Dai And If i commented the `RSsub.Close()` the page page keeps loading.. nothing showed up

Comment: I revised the code. I think the position of the end if should be before `RS.MoveNext()`. You should really step through your code line by line once to see if it is doing what it is supposed to and and where the errors pop up.

Comment: @codetantrik i updated the code and posted the answer below please check it there's also another problem have been going on. thanks you